# VB.NET Equivalent?

Tags: c#, vb.net

what is the equivalent of this C# code in VB.NET:

```
UctlTest uctlTest;
uctlTest= (UctlTest)Page.LoadControl("UserControls/UctlTest.ascx");
if (plcTest.Controls.Count == 0)
    plcTest.Controls.Add(uctlTest);
```

UctlTest: user control

plcTest: PlaceHolder

I tried this:

```
Dim uctlTestVB As UctlTestVB
uctlTestVB = CType(Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/UctlTestVB.ascx"), UctlTestVB)
If (Equals(uctlTestVB.Controls.Count, 0)) Then         
    plcTest.Controls.Add(uctlTestVB)
End If
```

But count in VB.NET is equal to 1 whereas in C# it is equal to 0.

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: Wow! StackOverflow is now used as code conversion tool. Great!

Comment: it is not about conversion, it is about returning 1 instead of 0 for the same code

Comment: @Shobhan This is why - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Comment: too simple, what is ur solution then?

Comment: Does the problem have to do with `Equals` when you should be using `=`. There are some cases where it produces unexpected results.

Comment: I used '='  and didnt solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a quick glance your code is checking a different control's child count.

C#: **plcTest**.Controls.Count

vs.

VB: **uctlTestVB**.Controls.Count

Yet the VB code still adds the loaded control to `plcTest`, but checks the count of the `uctlTestVB` instance.

Answer (score 3):

Notice you have an extra `"~"` symbol in your VB version, but not in your c#:

```
uctlTest= (UctlTest)Page.LoadControl("UserControls/UctlTest.ascx");
```

vs

`uctlTestVB = CType(Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/UctlTestVB.ascx"), UctlTestVB)`

Comment: got an exception: The virtual path '/UserControls/UctlReportingCentreSearchVB.ascx' maps to another application, which is not allowed.

Comment: Not `"/User` but `"User`. Leading slash means root, whereas lack of one means relative to current directory.

Answer (score -1):

The code is equivalent, your control probably isn't.

Why not load the same control in both snippets and verify they work the same.

Alternatively use the debugger/watch window and take a look at the Controls collection in both and find out how they differ